# IntelliJ Idea: TestNG Run configuration missing

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, run-configuration

Me and my collegue both have IntteliJ Idea version 2019.3.1 Community edition, but on my machine I have the run/debug configuration "TestNG" available and he does not (it is missing in the list of run/debug configurations). What could be the reason? Is there any plugin needed for TestNG run configuration to be available? Or any other thing needed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, stupid mistake: The TestNG plugin was not active, it simply needed to be activated under File -> Settings -> Plugins